# Which method to use in searching for a line in a file

Tags: c, search, fileparsing, file-search

I have a file with path names to files:

```
/my/path1
/my/path11
/my/path12
/my/path13
```

The file structure is that it has individual paths in each line. All I want to do is search for the existence of a string `/my/path1` or anyother in the above file many times

I could think of 2 methods.

1. every time get file contents line by line and then search the string. Advantage is that the file can be of anysize and I dont need to worry about buffer overflow.
2. Load the contents into a buffer and search it using the buffer. But as I dont have control over the file size I should be cautious here.

What is the best approach? I am working in unix. Is there any in-build library commands in C that I can make use of for this purpose? Or how can I accomplish the same task using `awk` in C code.

Comment: you have to use C and cannot just use a system command with the execv family of `sed`/`awk` ? otherwise exec: `sed -n '/pathtomatch/p' pathfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use stdio it will do the buffering for you. You can change its operation by using the function [setvbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/setvbuf/) to buffer more than a single line. `getline` can by used to check line by line.

Comment: `getline` is a part of C++, isn't it?

Comment: It is a part of stdio (GNU extension) - C. See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html Or you can use fgets

Comment: O, thanks. I did not know this function. I've read `man getline` and found out it quite useful. Especially its ability to reallocate dynamic buffer if it is not large enough to get all the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think loading all the file in memory is not a good idea. Using `fgets` and `strcmp` is the best way, I guess.